# onclick javascript -- > quotation marks

Tags: javascript

I have one `onclick` like this line:

```
onClick="function('value with special character 'like' quotation marks')"
```

How can I make it work?

The code broke when it "read" the quotation marks in the text ('like')

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xs9Zd/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape your quote marks:

```
onClick="function('value with special character \'like\' quotation marks')"
                                                ^     ^
```

That tells the JavaScript interpreter that those quotes are characters in the string, instead of an indication of the string's end.

Comment: hi! i know i can escape my quote marks, but i would like show it... 

I think it's impossible... :/

Comment: When i click the button, a dialog appears with a variable text...the text may be the quote marks...when the appear a text with quote marks the dialog dont work

Comment: What do you mean with _"don't work"_? What is happening, exactly?

Comment: dialog doesn't appear

Comment: And what code are you using to show a dialog, then?

Comment: @gui5711 — It really helps if *you do what the answer tells you to do* — http://jsfiddle.net/Xs9Zd/1/

Comment: hm...cool...i did a mistake when i put the \ in my code...sry ˆˆ

Can i do the same thing when i use double quotes ?

Comment: Yes, you can. For example, `\"like\"` will work, too.

Comment: Oh, looks like HTML doesn't recognize the escape characters. This should work instead: `'function("value with special character \"like\" quotation marks")'` Notice how I used single quotes for the `onClick` parameter, instead of double ones.

Comment: ouch X/

it's bad, because i dont know if my value will have double or single quotes...i got many values from my data base:

<?php while( $variable = $objSQL->fetch_object( $searchvariable) ) {
?>
<button onclick="function('<?php echo $variable->name ?>')"></button> <?php } ?>

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
onClick="function('value with special character &quot;like&quot; quotation marks')"
```

Comment: show the complete code, the problem must be some where else